# throwing custom exception of child class from a for each loop to parent class

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, foreach

```
   Class ProductServiceClass {

     Try {

         Product.callCustbusinessLogic();
     } catch (CustomStatusException cse) {

         jsonresponse.setError(cse.getError);

     }


 }

 Class Product throws CustomStatusException, Exception {

     public Customer callCustbusinessLogic() {
         for (type Customerlist: customer) {
             Try {
                 List < Customer > customerlist = new ArrayList < > ();

                 return customerlist.add(CustomerCheck.businessLogic());

             }
             Catch() {

                 // stack overflow question, how to throw the "Not a valid customer" occurred  
                 // in CustomerCheck  class to  ProductServiceClass 
             }
         }

     }
 }

 Class CustomerCheck throws CustomStatusException, Exception {

     public Customer businessLogic() {
         try {
             // business logic 
             return customer;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             CustomStatusException cse = new CustomStatusException();
             cse.setError("Not a valid customer");
             throw cse;
         }

     }

 }
```

ProductServiceClass calls Product class, Product class calls CustomerCheck. Exception happened in CustomerCheck class, so need to send the custom exception for that specific customer object to the parent class ProductServiceClass, but b/c there is a for each loop for the customerslist in the Product class couldn't send the custom exception to the parent class except standard runtime exception.

Can you please help how to throw the CustomStatusException to ProductServiceClass even there is a for each in the Product class?

Comment: This code has about 20 syntax errors in it. Please don't paste your random guess as to what you're trying to do, paste your _actual code_. Given this mess it's hard to tell where you're just fatfingering as you typed your question and where there's an actual problem.

Comment: Well, this is not valid Java syntax. A class does not throw exceptions, and keywords such as `class`, `try` and `catch` are lowercase.